# Select distinct of rows and show count of each value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to select a distinct selection of `[AssetManager].[AssetType]` with a count of how many times the Id of an Asset Type is being referenced from table `[AssetManager].[Asset]`. Please see below for an example:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Type Name | Asset Count |
+-----------+-------------+
| Phone     |           5 |
| Desktop   |          12 |
| Laptop    |          22 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

However, the query I'm trying isn't working at all, the furthest I've got is selecting Asset titles with an inner join of their Type name (I'm not great at SQL...). Please see below for my current Query:

```
SELECT
[Asset].[Title] AssetTitle,
[AssetType].[Title] TypeTitle
FROM
[AssetManager].[Asset]
INNER JOIN
[AssetManager].[AssetType]
ON
[Asset].[AssetType_Id] = [AssetType].[Id]
```

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes it complains about it not being an aggregate function

Comment: Add your code to the question and error message as it is shown to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said, all you needed to do is add a `GROUP BY` correctly:

```
SELECT
    [AssetType].[Title] TypeTitle
    , COUNT(*) [Asset Count]
FROM [AssetManager].[Asset]
     INNER JOIN [AssetManager].[AssetType]
        ON [Asset].[AssetType_Id] = [AssetType].[Id]
GROUP BY [AssetType].[Title]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OUTER APPLY` to get reference count from `[AssetManager].[Asset]` table

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT [AssetType].[Title] TypeTitle,
   M.TypeCount
FROM
[AssetManager].[AssetType]
OUTER APPLY(
  SELECT COUNT([Asset].[AssetType_Id]) AS TypeCount
  FROM [AssetManager].[Asset]
  WHERE [Asset].[AssetType_Id] = [AssetType].[Id]
)M
```

Comment: Thank you, and both work, but weirdly Radu's answer seems to be a much quicker execution than this. Thanks anyway